# get text of second child in div - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a kind of a online shopping cart
My problem is that I can't get the price of a single product showing in the shopping cart.

So here is my code

```
<div id="shoe_one">
  <img src="imgs/img_0.JPG" id="training_shoe" alt="purple adidas shoe" width="150" class="product">
  <p>Adidas Courtset</p>
  <p>Preis: 59,90 €</p>
  <input type="button" value="Warenkorb" class="button">
</div>
```

my js code:

```
let selectedItem = $(this).parent();

if(!contains) {

   //let price = selectedItem.("nth-child(3)").text();

   let addedProduct = $("<div class='newProduct'></div>");
   addedProduct.append(selectedImage.clone());
   addedProduct.append("<p>Anzahl: " + amount + "</p>" + "<p>" + price + "</p>");
   cart.append(addedProduct);
   content.append(cart);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your HTML stands, if you want to get the price text on clicking the button then you can target the previous *p* element.

**Demo:**

```js
$(".button").click(function(){
  let selectedItem = $(this);
  let price = selectedItem.prev("p").text();
  console.log(price);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="shoe_one">
    <img src="imgs/img_0.JPG" id="training_shoe" alt="purple adidas shoe" width="150" class="product">
    <p>Adidas Courtset</p>
    <p>Preis: 59,90 €</p>
    <input type="button" value="Warenkorb" class="button">
</div>
```